# AMP-state doesn't work with AMP.navigateTo()

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to use an amp-state for the target in AMP.navigateTo() but it doesn't bind it.

you can see an example for the issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/omartoma/qzbfaest/1/
once you click on the button, there is an exception in the console saying

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Target 'null' not supported.​​​`

Is there any workarounds to make it work or any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind **Uncaught (in promise) Error: Target 'null' not supported**.​​​ target is not set properly

```
    <button on="tap:AMP.navigateTo(url='https://google.com')" 
     target=targetState.target style="background:orange; cursor:grabbing">
     Go to google
    </button>
```

Working code:

```
       <a href="https://google.com" on="tap:AMP.navigateTo(url='https://google.com')"  target=targetState.target>Go to google</a>
```